# golang decode JSON request in nested struct and insert in DB as blob

Tags: mysql, json, go

I have a nested struct which I am using to decode JSON request.

```
type Service struct {
    ID       string `json:"id,omitempty" db:"id"`
    Name     string `json:"name" db:"name"`
    Contract struct {
        ServiceTime int    `json:"service_time"`
        Region      string `json:"region"`
    } `json:"contract" db:"contract"`
}
```

I am using blob type to store Contract in MySQL. To make it work , I would be needing to create a different struct with Contract as string to insert in DB. Can this be done in better way by using single struct only or is there any other elegant way ?

Comment: Are you using some orm or just `database/sql`, and what driver are you using?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This depends on what you use to talk to the database, but if you're using `database/sql` and a driver that provides support for this you can have your `Contract` type implement the [Valuer](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/driver/#Valuer) interface.

```
type Service struct {
    ID       string    `json:"id,omitempty" db:"id"`
    Name     string    `json:"name" db:"name"`
    Contract Contract `json:"contract" db:"contract"`
}

type Contract struct {
    ServiceTime int    `json:"service_time"`
    Region      string `json:"region"`
}

func (c *Contract) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    if c != nil {
        b, err := json.Marshal(c)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        return string(b), nil
    }
    return nil, nil
}
```

And then when you're executing the query just pass in the `Service.Contract` field and the driver should call the `Value` method.

```
sql := // INSERT INTO ...
svc := // &Service{ ...
db.Exec(sql, svc.ID, svc.Name, svc.Contract)
```

And to be able to retrieve the blob back from db and unmarshal it back into `Contract` you can have it implement the [Scanner](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Scanner) interface, again, if a type implements this the driver is expected to call it.

```
func (c *Contract) Scan(src interface{}) error {
    var data []byte
    if b, ok := src.([]byte); ok {
        data = b
    } else if s, ok := src.(string); ok {
        data = []byte(s)
    }
    return json.Unmarshal(data, c)
}

// ...

sql := // SELECT * FROM ...
svc := // &Service{ ...
db.QueryRow(sql, 123).Scan(&svc.ID, &svc.Name, &svc.Contract)
```

Comment: can u convert a struct type to string ? How ? Why in Service strict Contract has to be Contract pointer type ?

Comment: The `Contract` field on `Service` doesn't have to be a pointer. Depending on what format you want the blob to be (json, xml, gob, etc) you turn Contract into  a string by, for example, using one of the encoding packages.

Comment: @nebi I've updated the code examples to show how you would turn your Contract instance into a string and back using json. Note that I do not know what Go type is expected by the db driver you're using for blob columns, maybe `string` maybe `[]byte`... so you'll have to experiment a little.

Comment: I have implemented like this https://play.golang.org/p/Fb-VsWRAFa . But if I change *Contract to Contract, sql driver is throwing exception  :sql: converting Exec argument $3 type: unsupported type main.Contract, a struct
goroutine 22 [running]:
runtime/debug.Stack(0xc42004f720, 0x7e7620, 0xc420077620)
 /usr/local/go/src/runtime/debug/stack.go:24 +0x79
github.com/ant0ine/go-json-rest/rest.(*RecoverMiddleware).MiddlewareFunc.func1.1(0xbf0d50, 0xc02380, 0xc4201021e0)
 /home/vikash/go_packages/src/github.com/ant0ine/go-json-rest/rest/recover.go:41 +0x6e
panic(0x7e7620, 0xc420077620)

Comment: ok one sec. By the way, your scan implementation doesn't do anything because you are unmarshaling into `res` and not assigning that to `c`.

Comment: @nebi Try changing the receiver of the `Value` method to be non-pointer too, like so: https://play.golang.org/p/xy7Ji-Mk9D, also don't `panic` if you can return an error.

Comment: @nebi your `Scan` should look something like this https://play.golang.org/p/PH8NE2LpQI (without the comments of course)

Comment: I am surprised how it didn't complained :). I changed to https://play.golang.org/p/Kyvkvh2w_b . It still  works without issue.

Comment: Also I changed the receiver from *Contract to Contract, it looks fine. Wonder how that fixed it.

Comment: Can we do without using the db driver, as it will work for any db driver ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your last question.

Comment: It's like we are implementing Scan and Value methods explicitly which is supported by sql driver. But this won't work with non-sql driver.

Comment: Any code that expects the Scanner or Valuer interface can use Contract, it doesn't have to be an sql driver package, it could be anything. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Yes, Thanks @mkopriva