# Marshal JSON field in database to struct using Pop

Tags: go, orm

I'm using **Go Buffalo's ORM Pop** and want to store JSON in a field and be able to marshal it into a struct.

e.g.

schema.sql

```sql
CREATE TABLE tree (
    id uuid PRIMARY KEY,
    name text NOT NULL,
    fruit json,
);
```

main.go

```golang
type Tree struct {
    ID uuid.UUID `json:"id" db:"id"`
    Name string `json:"name" db:"name"`
    Fruit []Fruit `json:"fruit" db:"fruit"`
}

type Fruit struct {
    ID int `json:"id"`
    Name string `json:"name"`
}
```

I get the following error:

```sh
sql: converting argument $25 type: unsupported type []Fruit, a slice of struct
```

---

**UPDATE**

Based on feedback added the following methods:

```golang
type Fruits []Fruit

// Value implements the driver.Valuer interface
func (f Fruits) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    return json.Marshal(of)
}

// Scan implements the sql.Scanner interface
func (f * Fruits) Scan(value interface{}) error {
    var data []byte
    if b, ok := value.([]byte); !ok {
        data = b
        return errors.New("type assertion to []byte for Fruit failed")
    }
    return json.Unmarshal(data, &of)
}
```

Now receive the error:

```sh
Cannot fetch from database: unable to fetch records: sql: Scan error on column index 26, name "fruit": unexpected end of JSON input
```

---

**Update 2**

Updated Scan method to the following and fixed error:

```
// Scan implements the sql.Scanner interface
func (f * Fruits) Scan(value interface{}) error {
    var data = []byte(value.([]uint8))
    return json.Unmarshal(data, &of)
}
```

Comment: Don't know about pop, but the error seems to come from `database/sql` so I assume that's what pop's using underneath, in which case you should be able to do what you need by declaring a custom slice type e.g. `type FruitList []Fruit`, use that as the type of the field, and have this new type implement the scanner and valuer interfaces.

Comment: ... similar to what i've done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47336698/965900) although that's a struct and not a slice the same rules apply. If you have a custom type, struct or slice or whatever, and you want to control how a value of that type is stored to / read from the database you can do so by implementing the two interfaces.

Comment: thanks @mkopriva - I'm now getting the error: `Cannot fetch from database: unable to fetch records: sql: Scan error on column index 26, name "fruit": unexpected end of JSON input` I added a Value() and Scan() method to the Fruit struct.

Comment: Can you update the question by adding your Scan and Value implementations and also can you add the json that is stored in the db.

Comment: Didn't you want to store a slice of fruits into the column? Can you show how you're passing the individual field into the `row(s).Scan` method?

Comment: Also make sure, since your db column is NULLable, that the `src` variable passed to your `Scan` implementation is actually a json value that can be unmarshaled into the slice. The error seems to suggest that the `src` is empty, or incomplete in some other manner... check the contents of the column in the db and make sure it's kosher.

Comment: sorry, you're right. Update the Question again. I'm not explicitly calling the Scan method. This is being done by the ORM.

Comment: where you able to figure out what the contents of the column are and why Unmarshal is hitting the unexpected end of json input error?

Comment: Still working on it, but I see the `src` value being passed is `[]uint8` type. Trying to decode and see how I can handle it.

Comment: [`[]byte` is an alias for `[]uint8`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#byte) so that shouldn't be a problem, the content should be the problem. Try, before unmarshaling, printing the data you're attempting to unmarshal (`fmt.Printf("%q\n", string(data))`) and see if that looks like a valid json *array*.

Comment: seems to be working now thanks for your help @mkopriva

Answer (score 0):

Based on the help provided by @mkopriva

You need to provide Value and Scan methods for your struct

```golang
// Tree tall tree with many fruit
type Tree struct {
    ID uuid.UUID `json:"id" db:"id"`
    Name string `json:"name" db:"name"`
    Fruit []Fruit `json:"fruit" db:"fruit"`
}

// Fruit fruit found on a tree
type Fruit struct {
    ID int `json:"id"`
    Name string `json:"name"`
}

// Creates a splice of Fruit
type Fruits []Fruit

// Value implements the driver.Valuer interface
func (f Fruits) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    return json.Marshal(of)
}

// Scan implements the sql.Scanner interface
func (f * Fruits) Scan(value interface{}) error {
    var data = []byte(value.([]uint8))
    return json.Unmarshal(data, &f)
}
```

Comment: what's "of" variable here? did you mean f? strange that in the question stated as "fixed" the same renaming occurs.

Comment: Yeah it's a typo. I would have just copy pasta'd it from the Op